# Confused with Linear Algebra Proofs

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that this is true, but I am not sure how to prove it:

For $l×m$ matrix $A$ and $m×n$ matrix $B$, it will always be the case that $\operatorname{null}(B)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{null}(AB)$

My other question is:

Suppose $B$ is a square matrix of size $n$. What are two statements equivalent to $\operatorname{nullity}(B) > 0$ ?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Rank-nullity theorem does it for you.

Comment: The first statement you prove just by checking it..

Answer (score 1):

First, the dimensions of the matrices are irrelevant except for the fact that we want $AB$ to be a well defined matrix product. So you can safely ignore that for the moment.

You want to prove that $null(B)\subset null(AB)$. So pick a vector in $null(B)$, say $\vec{v}$. What can you say about the matrix-vector product $(AB)\vec{v}$?

You also want to say something about properties of a matrix with positive nullity. As the comment on your post suggests, the Rank-Nullity theorem does the trick for this task.

Comment: Could you expand on these and give examples? Sorry, I am pretty confused about how to get the answers for these...